# Scenerio where choosing myiasm and innodb makes a difference

Tags: mysql

I understand that myiasm doesn't support transactions like innodb.

Can someone give me an example of how choosing the correct db engine makes a difference in how things will operate.

Comment: Google "mysql myisam vs innodb" - this has been asked many many times

Answer (score 2):

MyISAM uses table level locking. InnoDB is row level.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html

Answer (score 1):

In many situations MyISAM will be faster for many operations by a factor of two or more, but the price you pay for this speed can be considerable if you're not prepared. A hard crash of the MySQL server process, which could be caused by any number of factors including a simple case of power loss, may corrupt MyISAM tables beyond recoverability. InnoDB tables are much more resistant and can usually be recovered in read-only mode in a typical worst-case scenario, if not repaired and restored automatically for you.

The simple reason for MyISAM being faster is it doesn't keep a journal and doesn't need to handle [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control). These things are important for most applications, though.

As always you should have timely backups of all your data.

I'd advise only using MyISAM for derivative data with extreme performance concerns. For this you would replicate from a source InnoDB table into MyISAM either on-demand, as a materialized view, or using triggers to keep things in sync. This is useful for making MyISAM act as a high-speed cache for your InnoDB data.

I would not advocate switching tables randomly to MyISAM in order to achieve better performance.